# JQuery - Toggle <TR> in table template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

i'm working on a  with a "display none" and i wanna show it after a clic on a bootstrap icon .

Here is the code :

Template :

```
<a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="{{order.cartId.id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{% trans 'show detail' %}"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="cat{{order.cartId.id}}" style="display:none"><td></td><td colspan="5">

                        {% for detailOrder in detailOrders %}
                            {% if detailOrder.cartId.id == order.cartId.id %}
                                <li>{{detailOrder.quantity}} {{detailOrder.unit}} de {{detailOrder.productId.name}} pour {{entreprise.currency.symbol}} {{detailOrder.totalPrice}}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <br><u>Livraison</u> : {{order.deliveryInstruction.instructions|truncatechars:60}}

        </td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
});
});
```

I don't have errors on my console so I'm a little lost about finding a soution.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day :)

Comment: can you makesure by inspecting your code that 
output od this {{order.cartId.id}} is same for data-prod-cat="{{order.cartId.id}}" and  class="cat{{order.cartId.id}}" ?

like data-prod-cat="1" and  class="cat1" ?

if yes then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  $(".toggler").click(function(){
     if($('.cat').css('display') === 'none'){
       $('.cat').css('display', 'block');
    }else{
       $('.cat').css('display', 'none');
    }  
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" class="toggler" value="Toggle"/>

<table>
<tr class="cat" style="display:none;">
     <td>Conlumn 1</td>
      <td colspan="5">Conlumn 2</td>
</tr>
  
  </table>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I will adapt it to my code. I will telll you if I have a problem but the snippet shows what I want. The problem is the complexity of the template ^^

Comment: If my answer helps, I'll be glad if you choose this answer... or if you mark that this answer was useful! Thanks!